# How can I create a node recursively using zookeeper client library on Java?

Tags: java, recursion, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I know this question has been already asked and answered for a zookeeper using python. The answer was good, however, I want something more related with the code. I've already implemented a method to create a node, but I want to do it recursively. The structure for my nodes will be like this:

ZOOKEEPER

- WEB SERVER

  - SERVER1
  - SERVER2
- MODULE CONNECTED

  - DATABASE MODULE

    - COMPUTER1
    - COMPUTER2
  - SERVICE MODULE

    - COMPUTER3
  - SEARCH MODULE

    - COMPUTER4

I have something like:

```
Zookeeper zk = new Zookeeper(...);

public void createNodeRecursively(String type) {
    final String node = "/" + type + "/" + info.getIP() + ":" + info.getPort(); // Correct line
    if (zk.exists("/" + type, null) == null) {
        Object ctx = new Object();
        StringCallback cb = new StringCallback() {
            public void processResult(int rc, String path,
                                Object ctx, String name) {
                if (name.equals("/" + type))// just in case
                    try {
                        zk.create(node, info.getBytes(),
                            Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE,CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        };
        zk.create("/" + type, info.getBytes(), Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE,
                            CreateMode.PERSISTENT, cb, ctx);

    } else
        zk.create(node, info.getBytes(), Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE,
                            CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);
    } 
}
```

As you can see I am using zk.create many times, so I want to make the method recursive in order to gain performance and have a better code, but I don't know how to start, I'll be very grateful if somebody can help me with this. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve a better performance:

```
public void createNode(NodePath nodePath, NodeData nodeData, NodeRights nodeRights, NodeCreationHandler nodeCreationHandler) throws KeeperException, InterruptedException, ZookeeperCreationException {

        if (zk == null) {
            throw new ZookeeperCreationException("The zookeeper client has not been instanced.");
        }       
        String targetPath = nodePath.getFullNodePath();
        targetPath = targetPath.substring(1, targetPath.length());
        byte[] serializedData = nodeData.serialize(new Object());
        String[] array = targetPath.split(ICoordinationConstants.BASE_ROOT_SPTR);
        String acum="";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            acum+=(ICoordinationConstants.BASE_ROOT_SPTR+array[i]);
            if (zk.exists(acum, null) == null) {
                zk.create(acum, serializedData, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.PERSISTENT);
            }
        }
        zk.create(acum+ICoordinationConstants.BASE_ROOT_SPTR+array[array.length-1], serializedData, Ids.OPEN_ACL_UNSAFE, CreateMode.EPHEMERAL);             
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper has useful properties:

1. Total order of (write) requests
2. Its asynchronous nature.

You can put on use that. 
Simply issue whole tree as a bunch of asynchronous requests in correct order and then wait, until all of them successfully execute. Of course, you can ignore 'NodeExists' exceptions (but it is not good, due of the fact, that such errors will be written to logs).