# how to copy folders content in zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

we want to copy in recursive way the path in zoo

```
/data/sparkru
```

to

```
/data/gtl/sparkru
```

example what we have from zookeeper cli shell under `/data/sparkru`

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 0] ls /data/sparkru
[gth.dwa.datas]
```

when I access the zoo cli we can see , the following flags

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTING) 0] ?
ZooKeeper -server host:port cmd args
        stat path [watch]
        set path data [version]
        ls path [watch]
        delquota [-n|-b] path
        ls2 path [watch]
        setAcl path acl
        setquota -n|-b val path
        history
        redo cmdno
        printwatches on|off
        delete path [version]
        sync path
        listquota path
        rmr path
        get path [watch]
        create [-s] [-e] path data acl
        addauth scheme auth
        quit
        getAcl path
        close
        connect host:port
```

what is the right way in zoo cli to copy the content from  `/data/sparkru` to `/data/gtl/sparkru`

Comment: You need to build a script that iteratively calls get and set for each znode

Comment: can you show me example ?

Comment: I don't have any. There's some code here for creating some nodes using Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069340/how-can-i-create-a-node-recursively-using-zookeeper-client-library-on-java   ... Maybe the Curator library has different methods that can help

Answer (score 0):

What I did is first copy the whole source node out, `./bin/solr zk cp -r zk:/source mylocal_dir -z 127.0.0.1:2181`, then upload it to the destination node using to `./bin/solr zk cp -r zk:/destination mylocal_dir -z 127.0.0.1:2181`. It works!